# Installing Ruby - EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails in EC2. I'm totally new at bash / EC2, so I feel like I'm missing something basic.

I have bash open, and have tried things like "yum install ruby", "gem install ruby" etc, but no luck.

I'm just trying to get the basic going so I can do a "hello world" kind of script...

I tried this: http://nathanhoad.net/how-to-ruby-on-rails-ubuntu-apache-with-passenger  but the first line gave the error "yum install ruby-full build-essential
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
You need to be root to perform this command."

Answer (score 1):

"You need to be root to perform this command" simply indicates that you don't have adequate permissions.  You'll notice in the tutorial you referenced that a lot of the commands begin with `sudo`.  That command allows you to run with the privileges of another user.  In this case, it suggests that you run the command as root.

You can do this by prefixing your command with `sudo` as in...

```
echo "Hello"
```

becomes

```
sudo echo "Hello"
```

(Note that `echo` isn't a great example of a command requiring elevated permissions, but it demonstrates the syntax.)

Comment: Thanks mate - that helped. I found the root access, sudo su did it (not sure what su is / does, but it worked...).   How would I install rails now? do i need to install ruby first, and then rails?

Answer (score 0):

I found this quick guide on the internet - although i skipped the extra dependencies part:

https://github.com/bvmake/WhosGotWhat/wiki/Installing-Rails-on-free-Amazon-EC2-Micro

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to the directory of your application and type `su`, you will be prompted for your password and you will be now using bash as root. Then type your command which you specified as `yum install ruby`.